# User Information List doesn't match Userinfo Table

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user-information-list

we are on sharepoint 2010. When I query the Userinfo table in the content database, there is one user that has tp_deleted = 0 and tp_IsActive = 1 but this user does not show up in the User Information List either via `http://sitecolleaction/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx` or with get-spuser.

I found that this user has a tp_ID that matches another user.

My first question would be how can two different users have the same tp_ID when that Id is used for group membership relations? we have multiple instances where two users share an ID.

second, is it possible to remove this row in anyway besides SQL?

Comment: We only have one site collection using this content database and in the site. Our only other content database in this deployment is the mysite database. The reason this is an issue is we have a process that automatically adds and removes users from sharepoint groups but we are getting false membership for users that share ID.

Comment: I thought there was only one site collection in the content db (there was only one for years) but recently another got added and sure enough the "duplicate IDs" are from different site collections. cleared things up for me, thanks.

Comment: Great! I converted my comment to an answer since that turned out to be the case. You can accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each site collection has its own collection of users.

My guess is this is happening because the user belongs to multiple site collections and just happens to have the same ID.

Check to make sure that there are no other site collections in the same content database that have users with the same ID.